# Is there a way to automate wifi in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi, ios-ui-automation

I want to automate the native wifi app of iOS to make it connect to a particular AP. Is there anyway to automate iPhone to do this through UI? In android I am able to this with ADB is there anything like that available in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode Instruments UIAutomation tool prohibits script from executing when the app is not in the foreground, which means that you can't leave the app with this tool. And you need an app to launch instruments with meaning that you need to be able to codesign the app you are using in order to profile it for the tool. Obviously the settings app is Apple's and there is no way that I know of to get the necessary files for the correct access.

My guess is that any other automation tool is constrained to the same limitations. The exception being if you are using a jailbroken device, but that's uncharted territory for me so I can't direct you there.